# Swift String from byte array without validating encoding?

Tags: swift, string, encoding, character-encoding, argon2-ffi

I'm trying to work with this [Argon2 implementation](https://github.com/ImKcat/CatCrypto/blob/master/Sources/Cryptos/Argon.swift). I'm implementing an existing protocol, so I don't have any flexibility in design, and the protocol treats various inputs to the function as byte sequences. However, that implementation treats inputs as `String`s. Is there any encoding that I can use which will allow me to convert an arbitrary byte sequence to a `String` without any validity constraints - that is, such that all possible byte sequences will convert without error?

Comment: You could Base64 your arbitrary unstructured binary data into a valid ut8 representation, and then pass that in. It's odd that they made their algorithm operated on `String` instead of `Data`, but I guess it's acceptable since that hash algorithm is targeted at passwords in particular.

Comment: Also, it looks like this code leaks all of the `cString`s it allocates, could you double check that if you get a chance? Just for my own curiosity

Comment: Unfortunately I can't base64 encode; the protocol relies on the two parties hashing exactly the same data, so base64 encoding would break that.

Comment: As for the leaking, I'm completely new to Swift (this is literally my first project), so I'll take your word on that :)

Comment: Welcome to Swift :) Hmmm I'm afraid you might be SOL here. You could consider modifying the library to accept a `Data`. You can then make convenience methods that bridge to/from `String`, to make the library still act like it does today. You could then submit a pull requset to the repo, could be useful for others, too. Alternatively, you could just look for other implementations that already use a `Data`.